# ImageIcon loading getting slower and slower

Tags: java, image, swing, imageicon, image-loading

In my java GUI application, I have some components that need to scale repeatedly, and I am doing this with the following code:

```
Image newImage = myimage.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_REPLICATE);

ImageIcon newIcon = new ImageIcon(newImage);

this.setIcon(newIcon);

this.setSize(width,height);

//increment width, height
```

At first this works fine, but after many iterations (a couple hundred) the new ImageIcon() constructor is taking an inordinate amount of time (about 1 second), based on some simple time checks.  The rest of the code is speedy.

Why does this happen after many iterations, and how can I make it stop slowing down as iterations increases?  (Loading the images in a background thread won't work, because loading the images is not a constant-time operation).

Comment: are you holding onto the old images so that they can not be garbage collected?

Comment: I don't believe so, since setIcon(newIcon) should push out the old icon, which only exists internally.  But there does seem to be some kind of memory leak because the program uses up an inordinate amount of RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html). It might not be the problem here, but you won't know until trying alternatives.

Comment: +1 for the interesting resource. I have been using scale instance myself and am happy with results but then I am scaling only once on object creation., e.g. ImageIcon resizedIcon = new ImageIcon(oldIcon.getImage().getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));

Comment: That was the problem!  We switched completely to Graphics2D transformations and both the lag and memory leak have disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I recall previous Q/A's where image loading was leading to memory issues.  I think you need to pursue the theory that this is a memory leak:

- Confirm that this is the problem by running your JVM with GC logging enabled, and see if there's some correlation between the log messages and the observed slowdown.  (It should take a minute or so to confirm, one way or another.)
- Use your favourite memory profiler to try to track down the leak.

Comment: how do i do GC logging with eclipse?

Comment: In the run configurations tool, set "-verbose:gc" as one of the JVM args.